# C++ register callback from server

Tags: c++, callback

I've prototype of callback as:

```
typedef void (*update)(int id,...);
typedef void (*destroy)(int id,...);
typedef void (*create)(int id, update* _update, destroy* _destroy);
```

And than create callbacks function:

```
void updateCB(int id,...){/*Add id to collection*/}
void destroyCB(int id,...){/*Remove id from collection*/}
void createCB(int id,update* _update, destroy* _destroy)
{
     //Register Callbacks
     *_update = updateCB; 
     *_destroy = destroyCB;
}
```

When I register callbacks compiler give me error:

> error: cannot convert 'ClassName::updateCB' from type 'void
>   (ClassName::)(int,...)' to type 'update {aka void (*)(int..)}'

How can I valid register callbacks?

Comment: A function pointer is not the same as a member function pointer. Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Also about pointers to members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use member functions which is impossible in this case. This happens because every member function ( if it is not static ) carries with itself hidden pointer to class instance called *this*.
You need to use global functions or static member functions.